# Copying from a specific part of a file to another with python

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, copy

I am trying to copy a specific part of a file to another one. The input file has four lines which start by the same name ("1" in the example given). I don't know exactly how I could take only the part of the file that is between the first "1" and the second "1" (more than 100 lines...):

·
·
1
·
·
·
1
·
·
·
1

I just started the following:

```
f_read = open(pathway, "r")
f_write = open(pathway, "w")
cnt = 0

with f_read as f1:
    for line in f1:
       if line.startswith("1"):
          cnt =+ 1
          if cnt == 2:
             break
```

And here I do not know how to specify the part of the file I want (from the first "1" until the second "1")...

Any ideas? 
Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use with to open both files. In your code if pathway is actually the same file you immediately open `pathway` to write after opening it to read so you are basically going to try to iterate over an empty file. You should use a temporary file to write to and then update the original if required.

```
with open(pathway) as f_read, open("temp_out.txt", "w") as f_write:
    for line in f_read:
         if line.startswith("1")
             for wanted_line in f_read:
                 # work on wanted lines
                 if wanted_line.startswith("1"):
                     break
with open("temp_out.txt", "w") as f_in, open(pathway, "w") as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        f_out.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically,

```
for line in in_file:
   if line.startswith('1'):
       break

for line in in_file:
   if line.startswith('1'):
       break
    <do stuff>
```

This uses the fact that python iterators are stateful, and the second loop starts where the first one has stopped, not from the beginning.